# SQL Query Date Related SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my query which runs perfectly

```
"SELECT RemBal FROM Sales WHERE CustomerName='" & CustomerName.Text & "'"
```

now i am trying to get the balance on two basis customer name & current date

```
"SELECT RemBal FROM Sales WHERE CustomerName='" & CustomerName.Text & "' AND SaleDate=#" & SaleDate.Value & "#"
```

now this query not giving me any error but not returning any value too
please help

Comment: i am trying to get the records from MS-ACCESS in vb6 code

Comment: if u are asking about date format then 02-01-2014 its a date picker

Comment: Try putting the date in a format of `yyyy-mm-dd`. I have had success with this access using this format in the past

Comment: if i use '" &  & "' its giving me error... data type mismatch

Comment: Can you say datatype of SaleDate in msaccess

Comment: using yyyy-mm-dd did solved the problem... MS-ACCESS database always needs some odd things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SaleDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
SaleDate.CustomFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

"SELECT RemBal FROM Sales WHERE CustomerName='" & CustomerName.Text & "' AND SaleDate=#" & SaleDate.Text()  &"# "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rembal 
FROM   sales 
WHERE  customername = '" & CustomerName.Text & "' 
       AND Format(saledate, 'dd/MM/yyyy') = '" & SaleDate.Value & "'
```